# ComboBoxes not updating Text with Enum as Datasource

Tags: c#, binding, combobox, enums

I'm trying to make a simple window that lets me configure a SerialPort based on a "default" serial Port. I'll show the code below, but first I'll just sum up what it does. I create my Form which initializes everything. I set a default SerialPort to a value, then I showDialog. The PortName, DataBits, and BaudRate all update to the correct "default" values. The 2 that don't update are the Parity and StopBits. The options in the combo boxes are correct, but the values it is showing are not. When I hit cancel on my form it says that stopbits (and presumably parity will say the same thing) says that enum value was out of the legal range. but no errors are shown when the form loads. I am stuck on this, can someone please help? I've changed the DefaultSerialPort set method many many times to try different ways of setting the values, but it hasn't changed my outcome. I've tried SelectedValue, SelectedItem. I've tried casting the Properties to their enum value type, i've done ToString(), all to no avail. So now for code.

So here is my test. The idea is that I am supposed to hit cancel on my form.The Strange non-standard values are just to show that the different values are updating correctly.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestSerialPortDialog()
    {
        var expected = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.Odd, 8, StopBits.OnePointFive);
        var actual = SerialPortDialog.GetSerialPortDialog(expected);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.PortName, actual.PortName);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.BaudRate, actual.BaudRate);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Parity, actual.Parity);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.DataBits, actual.DataBits);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.StopBits, actual.StopBits);

    }
```

**SerialPortDialog**

```
public class SerialPortDialog : Form
{
    public SerialPortDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static SerialPort GetSerialPortDialog(SerialPort sp)
    {
        SerialPort temp = null;
        using (SerialPortDialog icb = new SerialPortDialog())
        {
            icb.serialPortTablePanel.DefaultSerialPort = sp;
            icb.ShowDialog();
            temp = icb.serialPortTablePanel.InputSerialPort;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.serialPortTablePanel = new SerialPortTablePanel();
        this.serialPortTablePanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(serialPortTablePanel);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(280, 400);

        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
    private SerialPortTablePanel serialPortTablePanel;
}
```

**SerialPortTablePanel**

```
internal class SerialPortTablePanel : Control
{
    internal SerialPortTablePanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    internal SerialPort InputSerialPort
    {
        get
        {
            var com = comportCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            var baud = (int)baudRatCombo.SelectedItem;
            var parity = (Parity)parityCombo.SelectedValue;
            var data = (int)databitCombo.SelectedItem;
            var stop = (StopBits)stopbitCombo.SelectedValue;
            return new SerialPort(com, baud, parity, data, stop);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Initialize");
        var tbl = new TableLayoutPanel();
        var split1 = new SplitContainer();
        var split2 = new SplitContainer();

        this.SuspendLayout();
        tbl.SuspendLayout();
        split1.SuspendLayout();
        split1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        split1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
        split2.SuspendLayout();
        split2.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        split2.Panel2.SuspendLayout();

        split1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        split1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
        split1.SplitterDistance = split1.Width / 2;
        split1.SplitterWidth = 1;

        split2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        split2.SplitterDistance = 218;

        SetupTablePanel(tbl);
        tbl.Controls.Add(split1, 0, 6);
        tbl.Controls.Add(split2, 0, 5);

        comportCombo.Items.AddRange(GetComPorts());
        comportCombo.Text = "Select COM";

        baudRatCombo.Items.AddRange(GetBaudRate());
        baudRatCombo.Text = "Select BaudRate";

        parityCombo.DataSource = (System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Parity)));
        parityCombo.Text = "Select Parity";

        databitCombo.Items.AddRange(GetDatabit());
        databitCombo.Text = "Select DataBits";

        stopbitCombo.DataSource = (System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(StopBits)));
        stopbitCombo.Text = "Select StopBits";

        okButton = GetDefaultButton("OK", split1.Panel1);
        okButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        okButton.Enabled = false;

        cancelButton = GetDefaultButton("Cancel", split1.Panel2);
        cancelButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

        testButton = GetDefaultButton("Test", split2.Panel1);
        testButton.Click += testButton_Click;

        testLbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        split2.Panel2.Controls.Add(testLbl);


        split1.ResumeLayout(false);
        split1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        split1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        split2.ResumeLayout(false);
        split2.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        split2.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        tbl.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
    private void SetupTablePanel(TableLayoutPanel tbl)
    {
        tbl.ColumnCount = 1;
        tbl.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        tbl.Controls.Add(this.comportCombo, 0, 0);
        tbl.Controls.Add(this.baudRatCombo, 0, 1);
        tbl.Controls.Add(this.parityCombo, 0, 2);
        tbl.Controls.Add(this.databitCombo, 0, 3);
        tbl.Controls.Add(this.stopbitCombo, 0, 4);
        tbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tbl.RowCount = 7;
        tbl.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14.28571F));
        tbl.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14.28571F));
        tbl.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14.28571F));
        tbl.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14.28571F));
        tbl.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14.28571F));
        tbl.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14.28571F));
        tbl.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 14.28571F));

        this.Controls.Add(tbl);
    }
    private Button GetDefaultButton(string text, SplitterPanel sp)
    {
        Button butt = new Button();
        butt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        butt.MinimumSize = new Size(40, 40);
        butt.Text = text;

        sp.Controls.Add(butt);
        return butt;
    }
    void testButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var temp = InputSerialPort)
        {
            try
            {
                temp.Open();
                if (temp.IsOpen)
                {
                    okButton.Enabled = true;
                    testLbl.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    okButton.Enabled = false;
                    testLbl.BackColor = Color.Pink;
                }
                temp.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                okButton.Enabled = false;
                testLbl.BackColor = Color.Pink;
            }
        }
    }

    private string[] GetComPorts()
    {
        return SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    }
    private object[] GetBaudRate()
    {
        return new object[] { 4800, 9600, 19200, 115200 };
    }
    private object[] GetDatabit()
    {
        return new object[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    }

    public Button okButton;
    public Button cancelButton;
    public Button testButton;
    public SerialPort DefaultSerialPort
    {
        set
        {
            this.comportCombo.SelectedItem = value.PortName; //string[]
            this.baudRatCombo.SelectedItem = value.BaudRate; //object[]
            this.databitCombo.SelectedItem = value.DataBits; //object[]
            this.parityCombo.SelectedItem = value.Parity; //Parity enum
            this.stopbitCombo.SelectedItem = value.StopBits; //StopBits enum
        }
    }

    private ClickComboBox comportCombo = new ClickComboBox();
    private ClickComboBox baudRatCombo = new ClickComboBox();
    private ClickComboBox parityCombo = new ClickComboBox();
    private ClickComboBox databitCombo = new ClickComboBox();
    private ClickComboBox stopbitCombo = new ClickComboBox();
    private Label testLbl = new Label();
}
```

Thank you for your time

**EDIT**

ugh and the annoying part of it all is that I have this code in a seperate project all together and it works as expected...

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboBox2.DataSource = new int[] { 4800, 9600, 19200, 115200 };
        comboBox3.DataSource = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        comboBox4.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Parity));
        comboBox5.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(StopBits));

        var sp = new SerialPort("COM2");
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = sp.PortName;
        comboBox2.SelectedItem = sp.BaudRate;
        comboBox3.SelectedItem = sp.DataBits;
        comboBox4.SelectedItem = sp.Parity;
        comboBox5.SelectedItem = sp.StopBits;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out the reason why I was having such a hard time had to do with timing.. well that's a guess, but the problem went away when I changed my form to have a Load event fire when it was done then set the default serial port.

```
public class SerialPortDialog : Form
{
    public SerialPortDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += SerialPortDialog_Load;
    }

    void SerialPortDialog_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serial != null)
        {
            serialPortTablePanel.DefaultSerialPort = serial;
        }
    }
    public SerialPortDialog(SerialPort sp) : this()
    {
        this.serial = sp;
    }
    public static SerialPort GetSerialPortDialog(SerialPort sp)
    {
        SerialPort temp = sp;
        using (SerialPortDialog icb = new SerialPortDialog(sp))
        {
            if (icb.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                temp = icb.serialPortTablePanel.InputSerialPort;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.serialPortTablePanel = new SerialPortTablePanel();
        this.serialPortTablePanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(serialPortTablePanel);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(280, 500);

        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
    private SerialPortTablePanel serialPortTablePanel;
    private SerialPort serial;
}
```